# Add row to stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, row

What's the syntax to add a pre-defined row to the return values of a stored procedure?

Let's say I select some rows from a View and, **additionally**, want the procedure to return another **pre-defined row**.

Is this only possible by filling up a table?

Comment: why don't you use a table-valued function and union with view?

Comment: stored procedures can return a value but not a set of values.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `UNION ALL`.

You can run a query like this:

```
select . ..
from . . .
union all
select . . .;
```

Note that without an `ORDER BY`, result sets are *unordered*.  So the additional row might not be the "last" in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with union all, and if you want the predefined row to be the last row you can add an order by like this

```
select 0 as sortvalue, 
       table1.*
from   table1
union all
select 1 as sortvalue,
       predefined values...
order by 1
```